# How to use Stream in cupy to achieve parallel computation in code?

Tags: python, stream, cupy

I want to use CUDA streams to speed up computation on the GPU. The following code achieves signal processing by repeatedly running a segment of code. I hope that the code can perform parallel operations to reduce processing time.

My test code is as follows:

```py
import cusignal
import cupy as cp
import time

def process_signal(signal0, signal1,FIR6):
    signal_te = cp.multiply(signal0, signal1)
    signal_lfilter = cusignal.lfilter(FIR, 1, signal_te) 
    signal_resample = signal_lfilter[0:-1:4] 
    return signal_resample 

streams = [cp.cuda.Stream() for _ in range(20)]
signal0_gpu = cp.array(signal0) 
FIR_gpu = cp.array(FIR[0]) 
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(40):
    signal1_i = cp.array(signal1[i][0]) 
    with streams[i%20]:
        signal_resample  = process_signal(signal0_gpu, signal1_i, FIR)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
end_time = time.time()
print("Time spent：", end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

I created 20 streams here and processed 40 segments of signal processing code, which took a total of 1.3393337726593018 seconds. However, if I run only one segment of code, it takes 0.0772559642791748 seconds. From a timing perspective, this does not seem like parallel processing. I want to know what went wrong with my code and how I can modify it.

Comment: In your `for` loop you're creating `signal1_i` without a stream, that will cause your entire loop to become synchronous. You should move that inside `with stream ...` block or create all the data before enqueuing work onto multiple streams. I suggest also looking at some of the [CuPy stream examples](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/tree/main/examples/stream) for better understanding.